# Connectivity to Android market from Device

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i m using In app billing in my app i m testing it after uploading it on goolge play account i added test products and testing it on device. Note all the pre requisits  are complete for in-app billing.
but it is saying "cannot  connoect to market" any suggestion/help Thank you

Comment: I am getting same problem. Please help someone!

Comment: Can you show some Code? Did you added your gmail acc as a test account in play market?

Comment: i added the required things 
1- public key 
2- google account
3- test acouts
i`ve test that code sperately that works fine but when i used it as it is then it is not working the way it should

Comment: @usman well, if you have done "all the pre requisits", then you wouldn't be having this bug. It seems a bit unfair to vote Stefano down.

Comment: @ Richard Le Mesurier i`ve not vote him down and being a developer i should not discourage any response and i did not discourage him of his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have came to know after a full day brain storming and testing that there was an issue of in-App billing with Tab Widget in my case i made another test project 1st test it with tab for in-App Billing but had the same error and after that i removed the tab widget and then tried the in app billing and it worked fine so what i conclude is that in my case there was an issue of tab widget.

Answer (score 0):

remember to configure the device with a google account and to include your email in market test account list.

you should also include billing permission to app manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Comment: i`ve already mentioned that "all the pre requisits for in app billing are completed "

Comment: also remember to sign your application with a personal key when you compile it. In Eclipse, you should use the "export signed application..." option in Android Tools menu (right click on your project folder)

Comment: how can I know if you're aware of ALL of them? :)

Comment: you're not providing specific information, I try to help anyway and you vote me down???